# STM32F407 - SDIO | FATFS - save file to sd card

Tags: c, stm32, sd-card, fatfs

**Problem :**

> Even the card is present or not, The SD card is mounted .
> I can’t write a file to the sd card.

**Context :**

I read a lot of books, documentations and tutorials, I can’t find a way to make it work.
From the STM IDE debugger, I can’t get rich errors as I find with Python or Javascript. This is why I’m asking help. Except with printf but this is only personal comment to my terminal.

**Technical specifications :**

> Mac OS - 10.15.4

> CubeMX - 5.6.1

> STM32 IDE - SDIO / FATFS

> STM32F407VG - Discovery board

**SD Card Board :**

https://www.amazon.fr/Module-Lecteur-Carte-Double-Arduino/dp/B07MG4LZRW/ref=pd_rhf_se_p_img_12?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=WJGA2Y1B8XK0H658VV8C

**code**

Main.c

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under Ultimate Liberty license
  * SLA0044, the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with
  * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                             www.st.com/SLA0044
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
 
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "fatfs.h"
 
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
 
/* USER CODE END Includes */
 
/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
 
/* USER CODE END PTD */
 
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */
 
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */
 
/* USER CODE END PM */
 
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SD_HandleTypeDef hsd;
 
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
 
/* USER CODE END PV */
 
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SDIO_SD_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
 
/* USER CODE END PFP */
 
/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
extern char SDPath[4];   /* SD logical drive path */
extern FATFS SDFatFS;    /* File system object for SD logical drive */
extern FIL SDFile;       /* File object for SD */
FIL myFile;
UINT myBytes;
/* USER CODE END 0 */
 
/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
 
  /* USER CODE END 1 */
 
  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/
 
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();
 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
 
  /* USER CODE END Init */
 
  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
 
  /* USER CODE END SysInit */
 
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SDIO_SD_Init();
  MX_FATFS_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
 
  if(f_mount(&SDFatFS, SDPath, 0) == FR_OK)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
 

 
      if(f_open(&SDFile, "F7FILE2.TXT", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE) == FR_OK)
      {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
 
        char myData[] = "Helllo";
 
        if(f_write(&SDFile,myData, sizeof(myData), &myBytes) == FR_OK)
        {
 
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
 
        }
        f_close(&SDFile);
      }
    }
  else
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  }
 
 
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
 
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
 
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
 
/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
 
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 72;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 3;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
 
  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
 
/**
  * @brief SDIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SDIO_SD_Init(void)
{
 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 0 */
 
  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 0 */
 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 1 */
 
  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 1 */
  hsd.Instance = SDIO;
  hsd.Init.ClockEdge = SDIO_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
  hsd.Init.ClockBypass = SDIO_CLOCK_BYPASS_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDIO_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.BusWide = SDIO_BUS_WIDE_1B;
  hsd.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDIO_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.ClockDiv = 3;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 2 */
 
  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 2 */
 
}
 
/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
 
  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
 
  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
 
  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD12 PD13 PD14 PD15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
}
 
/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
 
/* USER CODE END 4 */
 
/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
 
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}
 
#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
 
/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

---

What I have done since the first post.

The problem comes from the open function. I got a `FR_DISK_ERR`.

When debugging, the script follows this line :

```
FRESULT f_open (
    FIL* fp,            /* Pointer to the blank file object */
    const TCHAR* path,  /* Pointer to the file name */
    BYTE mode           /* Access mode and file open mode flags */
)
{
    FRESULT res;
    DIR dj;
    FATFS *fs;
#if !_FS_READONLY
    DWORD dw, cl, bcs, clst, sc;
    FSIZE_t ofs;
#endif
    DEF_NAMBUF


    if (!fp) return FR_INVALID_OBJECT;

    /* Get logical drive */
    mode &= _FS_READONLY ? FA_READ : FA_READ | FA_WRITE | FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_CREATE_NEW | FA_OPEN_ALWAYS | FA_OPEN_APPEND | FA_SEEKEND;
    res = find_volume(&path, &fs, mode); /* The script failed at this line  ! */
    if (res == FR_OK) {
        dj.obj.fs = fs;
        INIT_NAMBUF(fs);
        res = follow_path(&dj, path);   /* Follow the file path */
```

The script failed at the line `res = find_volume`  and jump to the end of the open function :

```
    if (res != FR_OK) fp->obj.fs = 0;   /* Invalidate file object on error */

    LEAVE_FF(fs, res);
```

In regard of the variables asked by the open function :

```
FRESULT f_open (
    FIL* fp,            /* Pointer to the blank file object */
    const TCHAR* path,  /* Pointer to the file name */
    BYTE mode           /* Access mode and file open mode flags */
)
```

I think variables fp and mode are OK. The mistake could be about the `const TCHAR* path`  as you said.

```
f_open(&SDFile, "F7FILE2.TXT", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
```

I have investigated about the `find_volume` but I can't follow the behaviour when debugging... there is types of error the function can return :

**1 - Get sector size (multiple sector size cfg only)**

```
#if _MAX_SS != _MIN_SS                  /* Get sector size (multiple sector size cfg only) */
    if (disk_ioctl(fs->drv, GET_SECTOR_SIZE, &SS(fs)) != RES_OK) return FR_DISK_ERR;
    if (SS(fs) > _MAX_SS || SS(fs) < _MIN_SS || (SS(fs) & (SS(fs) - 1))) return FR_DISK_ERR;
#endif
```

**2 - An error occured in the disk I/O layer**

```
    /* Find an FAT partition on the drive. Supports only generic partitioning rules, FDISK and SFD. */
    bsect = 0;
    fmt = check_fs(fs, bsect);          /* Load sector 0 and check if it is an FAT-VBR as SFD */
    if (fmt == 2 || (fmt < 2 && LD2PT(vol) != 0)) { /* Not an FAT-VBR or forced partition number */
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {       /* Get partition offset */
            pt = fs->win + (MBR_Table + i * SZ_PTE);
            br[i] = pt[PTE_System] ? ld_dword(pt + PTE_StLba) : 0;
        }
        i = LD2PT(vol);                 /* Partition number: 0:auto, 1-4:forced */
        if (i) i--;
        do {                            /* Find an FAT volume */
            bsect = br[i];
            fmt = bsect ? check_fs(fs, bsect) : 3;  /* Check the partition */
        } while (LD2PT(vol) == 0 && fmt >= 2 && ++i < 4);
    }
    if (fmt == 4) return FR_DISK_ERR;       /* An error occured in the disk I/O layer */
```

**3 - Check if bitmap location is in assumption (at the first cluster)**

```
/* Check if bitmap location is in assumption (at the first cluster) */
        if (move_window(fs, clust2sect(fs, fs->dirbase)) != FR_OK) return FR_DISK_ERR;
```

There is a screenshoot about the FATFS configuration but even with `FF_USE_LFN`  set to  `1   Enable LFN with static working buffer on the BSS. Always NOT thread-safe.`  I got `FR_DISK_ERR` ...

Do you have an idea ?

[image: CubeMX FATFS configuration]

**Final answer :**

From the find_volume function, I found Exfat was not enable as `FF_USE_LFN`

I got a FR_NO_FILE_SYSTEM. I take a time to take a look on the web and I found SDIO on STM32 can't work without DMA... Also you need to set-up pull-up resistors except for the CLK.

This post solve all my problems :

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkWceSAF/stm32f411re-stm32cube-fatfs-sdio-sdcard-always-returns-frdiskerr

Also keep the wiring as short as possible between the stm32 card and your external sd card proto board.

I got a lot of problem because I was using long wiring.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess (without seeing you FatFs configuration) is going to be that you haven't enabled Long File Names (LFS). As such FatFs is only configured to work with [8.3 filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). These can only be 8 characters long. As such `"F7FILE2.TXT"` isn't being handled properly.

To [enable LFS](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/config.html) you should set `FF_USE_LFN = 1`. (More options are available and please pick the one most applicable to your situation.)

Comment: I have updated the question with FATFS configurations. thank you